# Integrate ${Category.displayName} in Demandware content slot

Tags: categories, demandware

There is way to show ${Category.displayName} in regular Demandware Content Slot? Please let me know if there are other options how I can show actual category name inside a content asset.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a Category type content slot configuration you can access the categories you configured via `${slotcontent.content}` which is an iterator of categories (you can use only the first element in your use case and ignore if there is more than one category).